# MIPS (or SPIM): Loading floating point numbers

Tags: c, mips, spim

I am working on a little mini compiler while trying to learn some MIPS here.  Here's my issue:

MIPS has an instruction li (load immediate) which would work like this

```
li $5,100
```

which would load 100 into register 5.

However, I need to load floats into registers right now and am struggling with figuring out a way to do it...since li $5,2.5 does not work.

Anyone have any advice?

I am working in C, I was thinking I could somehow get the integer representation of the float I am working with (i.e. so the floats binary representation == the ints binary representation) then load the "integer" into the register and treat it like a float from then on.

Maybe its too late but Im stuck right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to use the floating point registers to load your floats.

Instead of:

```
li $5,2.5
```

Try:

```
li.s $f5,2.5
```

Take a look at mfc1 and mtc1 instructions to move between integer and floating point registers.

Comment: Thanks, that .s did the trick.  I should probably hit the hay if I missed that.  Have a good night.

Comment: That seems to be a pseudoinstruction.  How would I actually go about doing it?  (MARS doesn't support li.s).  Only thing I can think of is to load 25 into $t0, load 10 into $t1, convert each to float, and then divide.

Answer (score 32):

MARS **does not** appear to have any instructions/pseudo instructions that load floating point immediate values into floating registers.  Instead, you need to put the floating point value in memory and load the register from memory:

```
.data
fp1: .double 2.5
fp2: .double -0.75

.text   
l.d $f0, fp1
l.d $f2, fp2
```