# Typecasting in MIPS

Tags: casting, mips

how can I convert this kind of code block to MIPS?

`gap = (int)(gap / 1.3);`

Comment: See the instruction set reference: http://vhouten.home.xs4all.nl/mipsel/r3000-isa.html and http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first load 1.3 to a f reg. ref: [MIPS (or SPIM): Loading floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589233/mips-or-spim-loading-floating-point-numbers)

```
.data

number: .double 1.3

.text

l.s $f2, number
```

now load f1 to (double)gap

```
mtc1 $a0, $f1
cvt.d.w $f1, $f1
```

then set $f3 = (double)(gap / 1.3)

```
div.d $f3, $f1, $f2
```

now convert it to int

```
cvt.w.d $f3, $f3    
mfc1 $s2, $f3
```

thats all

Comment: I think you meant to say `.d` in every place where you have `.s`. The former means `double` and the latter means `float`, or single precision.

Comment: @markgz yeah you're right. forgot to update this post after realizing