# (Runtime Exception) Address out of range in MIPS assembly program

Tags: assembly, mips

The point of this program is to read 11 doubles, store them in an array and compute the average value. Here is the code:

```
    .include "../../ac1_macros.h"
    .eqv size, 11
    .data
    .align 4
array:  .double 0:size
str1:   .asciiz "Insert 11 numbers: "
str2:   .asciiz "Average: "

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, ($sp)
    la $t0, array   
    print_str(str1)
    li $t1, 0

fill_array:
    read_double()
    s.d $f0, ($t0)
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    addi $t0, $t0, 8 # proceed to the next element
    bne $t1, size, fill_array
    jal average
    lw $ra, ($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4
    mov.d $f12, $f0
    print_str(str2)
    print_double_simple
    jr $ra

average:
    li $t2, 0
    l.d $f0, 0
sum:    
    l.d $f2, array($t2)
    add.d $f0, $f1, $f2
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    blt $t2, size, sum
    l.d $f3, size
    div.d $f0, $f0, $f3
    jr $ra
```

At "l.d $f0, 0" I get Runtime exception address out of range. Can't figure out why! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> l.d FRdest, address

You're passing in `0` as the address...

Try doing:

```
li.d $f0, 0
```

Comment: li.d is not a recongnized operator in MIPS assembly

Comment: Look at this answer for how to do it without pseudoinstructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12916015/1715829