# How to compare a double value in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, precision, cpu-registers

I have a loop that ends with this

```
bne $f2, $zero, loop
```

It should return to the beginning of the loop if $f2 equals zero, but I'm getting this error.

"$f2": operand is of incorrect type

How do I compare a double value to zero?

Comment: You will need to use floating point comparison and branch. Consult an instruction set reference. Alternatively, if you don't have signed zero, you can move the value back into an integer register and keep the `bne` since a floating point zero is all 0 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use something like

```
li.d $f0, 0        # store the value 0 in register $f0
c.ne.d $f0, $f2    # $f0 != $f2?
bc1t loop          # if true, branch to the label called "loop"
```

- http://www.ece.lsu.edu/ee4720/2014/lfp.s.html
- https://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/mips/data-comparison.xhtml
- [MIPS (or SPIM): Loading floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589233/mips-or-spim-loading-floating-point-numbers)
- https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~childers/CS0447/lectures/SlidesLab92Up.pdf